# Unable to view groups through azure access panel

Tags: azure

I have enabled (`DELEGATED GROUP MANAGEMENT ENABLED, USERS WHO CAN USE SELF-SERVICE FOR SECURITY GROUPS (all) and USERS CAN CREATE SECURITY GROUPS)` in azure ad directory and created a normal user.

Also created a security group with group policy (group requires owners approval), now when i login as a normal user through access panel i am unable to view any group to request for a self join.

I have noticed the groups tab shows up in access panel when i assign any of the admin roles but not when the organization role is set to user.

Is it necessary for a user to have an admin role to request for a group?

PS: I have azure AD premium license enabled